# How do I return the pointer to a class scoped array from a class function?

Tags: c++, oop

The code below does not compile, but if I make _foo static, it will. Why? And, more importantly, **is there a way to make the code below work, without making _foo static**?

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    const char** getFoo() const {
        return _foo;
    }
private:
    const char* _foo[ 10 ];
};
```

Comment: You have a `const` function, so not allowed to return non-const pointer to member.

Comment: That was, of course, it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

So, like Bo Persson pointed out in his comment, the function is const but returns a non-const pointer. The solution is thus:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    const char* const* getFoo() const {
        return _foo;
    }
private:
    const char* _foo[ 10 ];
};
```

Comment: or make foo mutable.